# How to convert result of mcapply to dataframe? Rbind gives errors

Tags: r, parallel-processing

Running do.call(rbind, result) to the resulting list from running 'mcapply' gives an error. This happens when running the markdown file automatically using make.

I **do not** get the same error when I am running the code block by block in the R console.

```
library(parallel)
filenames <- list.files(full.names=TRUE)

ALL <- mclapply(filenames, function(i){read.csv(i, header=FALSE)}, mc.cores=4)

combined <- do.call("rbind", ALL)
colnames(combined) <- c("Trip.Distance","Trip.Duration")
```

[image]

Hope somebody can help me, thanks!

Comment: as the error says, your `ALL` does not have all `.csv` files with the same number of columns, so you cannot _row-bind_ them

Comment: Also, are you sure all files are `.csv` in your directory?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Vitali Avagyan, I realised that my makefile and Rmd file are also on the same directory as the .csv files, hence the error.

I created a new directory containing only the .csv files and it solved the issue.